# Yocto adding third system service to recipe file causes others not to start

Tags: linux, yocto, systemd, bitbake, recipe

I am modifying a Yocto .bb recipe file to add and enable 3 systemd services in my image. Below shows the bottom of my recipe file with just two services added and enabled. This works!

app1.service is a one shot basic service that runs once and app2.service waits for app1.service to complete first by using "*After=app1.service"* in the app2.service file. All this works fine without issues :

```
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir} \
               ${systemd_unitdir}/system/app1.service \
               ${systemd_unitdir}/system/app2.service \
"
inherit systemd

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "app1.service app2.service"
```

Now, I add a third service called app3.service as shown below. This service should also wait for app1.service to complete first in the same manner

```
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir} \
               ${systemd_unitdir}/system/app1.service \
               ${systemd_unitdir}/system/app2.service \
               ${systemd_unitdir}/system/app3.service \

"
inherit systemd

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "app1.service app2.service app3.service"
```

However, when I start my device, only app3.service runs, with app1.service and app2.service reporting the following as below which tells me that the service is not enabled somehow:

```
app1.service - app1
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/app1.service; disabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

This I cannot understand. I would expect all three services to be enabled because I added them to SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}.

Is there something wrong with adding three services in the manner in which I do in the .bb recipe file? Thanks

app1.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=app1 
ConditionPathExists=/app
After=network.target uncrypte_app.service uncrypte_data.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/app
ExecStart=/app/app1
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

app2.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=app2 
ConditionPathExists=/app
After=network.target uncrypte_app.service uncrypte_data.service app1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/app
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/run/app2.pid
ExecStart=/app/app2 start
ExecStop=/app/app2 stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

app3.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=app3
ConditionPathExists=/storage
After=network.target uncrypte_app.service uncrypte_data.service app1.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/storage
ExecStart=/storage/app3
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: show us those service files. do you have dependencies set in them on each other? check whether they're set in the correct order

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Thanks for your reply. I've included the three service files in my question.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Can you see anything that appears incorrect in what i'm doing? app1.service should run first , app2.service and app3.service should start after app1.service finishes. However, with these three services added like this, only app3.service runs and the others are Inactive when unless i explicitly enable them. If I only have app1.service and app2.service added, then they both work fine

Comment: Did you try to add RequiresMountsFor option in your service files?

Comment: @Nayfe I didn't try this. How would it help in my case?

Comment: What I wonder is if your `ConditionPathExists` returns true in case your /app is mounted and not available at boot time? Its one of the reason a valid service does not start?

Comment: @Nayfe The system service uncrypte_app.service mounts the /app partition. The services depend on this uncrypte_app.service to complete using "ConditionPathExists" before running them. This all works fine if I only have app1.service or app2.service , so I don't know why adding app3.service would cause a problem with the mounting.

Comment: Problem is that /app mountpoint should exists before app1 is launched? You could check if /app/X is mounted with `RequiresMountsFor` instead. Did you check boot logs with `journalctl -b` to see if any error appears?

Comment: Ok thanks I will check it. What happens if RequiresMountsFor fails tho? Does it wait? In the case of app1.service, this is a oneshot type, so maybe it doesn't run again if fails?

Answer (score 0):

Because the recipe inherits the systemd class, have you tried to define the `SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE` variable ?

This variable :

> specifies whether the service you have specified in SYSTEMD_SERVICE should be started automatically or not.

You can add the following line into your custom package recipe

```
  SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "enable"
```

Comment: I haven't tried explicitly stating this. My understanding is that SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "enable" is the default action unless we set SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "disable". With the two services they are enabled by automatically for me, but adding the third causes the first two to not be enabled. Does the order in which I add the services to SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} matter do you think? Thanks

Comment: I have just tried adding SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "enable" to the end of the recipe file and it still doesn't work.